# Select radio button with a specific value within a series of groups in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a series of generated groups of radio buttons. I want to iterate through the groups, and do attr('checked',true) to the radio with a value determined by the substr() of a hash (stored in a text box with id="hash" for now).

```
var hashPosition = 0;

$("section").each(function(){
  var hashCode = $("#hash").val().substr(hashPosition, hashPosition + 1);
  if(hashCode > 5){ hashCode = 0; }
  $("input[value='"+ hashCode +"']").attr('checked', true);
  hashPosition++;
});
```

The hash is just a series of numbers from 1-5. (ex. "012345123450")
The HTML looks like this:

```
  <li>
    <section>All snoots must be booped.</section>
    <section>
      <input type="radio" name="c1i1a" id="c1i1-5" title="Strongly Agree" value="5" />
      <input type="radio" name="c1i1a" id="c1i1-4" title="Agree" value="4" />
      <input type="radio" name="c1i1a" id="c1i1-3" title="Neutral" value="3" />
      <input type="radio" name="c1i1a" id="c1i1-2" title="Disagree" value="2" />
      <input type="radio" name="c1i1a" id="c1i1-1" title="Strongly Disagree" value="1" />
      <input type="radio" name="c1i1a" id="c1i1-0" title="No Opinion" value="0" />
    </section>
  </li> ... and so on
```

This code doesn't work because it is setting the value of every input[value=n] in the document. I need to specify $this section's inputs. But I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the input only inside the current section being iterated over, reference `this` inside the `each` callback (to get to the section), and use `.find` to get to the matching input which is a descendant of the section:

```
$(this).find("input[value='" + hashCode + "']").attr('checked', true);
```